# How to sum by group an "Origin-Destination" data frame?

Tags: r, sum, summary

I have this kind of data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(Origin=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
               Var=   c(2,4,1,3,5,6,2,1),
               Desti= c(2,2,3,2,1,2,1,3))
```

I would like to get the sum of `Var`, for each value of `Origin`, grouped by `Desti` (Out.x) and by `Origin` (In.x). The result would be for `df`:

```
  Out.1 Out.2 Out.3 In.1 In.2 In.3
1     0     6     1    0    5    2
2     5     3     0    6    3    6
3     2     6     1    1    0    1
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this helps

```
res <-  cbind(xtabs(Var~., df), xtabs(Var~Desti+Origin, df))
colnames(res) <- paste(rep(c("Out", "In"), each=3), 1:3, sep=".")
res
#  Out.1 Out.2 Out.3 In.1 In.2 In.3
#1     0     6     1    0    5    2
#2     5     3     0    6    3    6
#3     2     6     1    1    0    1
```

Or, the above can be simplied

```
 r1 <- xtabs(Var~., df)
 res <- cbind(r1, t(r1)) #change the `column names` accordingly
```

Or using `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
res1 <- cbind(acast(df, Origin~Desti, value.var='Var', sum),
               acast(df, Desti~Origin, value.var='Var', sum))
colnames(res1) <- colnames(res)
```